# Use Binding in Resource without styles

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I have a `MultiBinding` defined as follows:

```
<MultiBinding StringFormat="{0}_{1}">
    <Binding Path="..." />
    <Binding Path="..." />
</MultiBinding>
```

I need to use it in multiple places, and want to define it in my resources, as:

```
<MultiBinding x:Name="MyDefaultBinding" StringFormat="...">
    <!-- etc -->
</MultiBinding>
```

However, I now cannot work out how to use it. I tried a `StaticResource` like:

```
<TextBlock Text="{StaticResource MyDefaultBinding}" 
           Style="{StaticResource SomeOtherStyle}" />
```

This gave me a compile error: *"Invalid resource type: expected type is 'string', actual type is 'MultiBinding'."*.

When I tried to access it using a `Binding` like:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyDefaultBinding}}" 
           Style="{StaticResource SomeOtherStyle}" />
```

It compiles, but at runtime the text in the `TextBlock` is set to *"System.Windows.Data.MultiBinding"* instead of the expected value.

I've seen suggestions which propose wrapping the `MultiBinding` in a `Style`, however I already have other shared styles defined on the controls where I need to use the binding.

Can I evalute a binding defined in resources without wrapping it in a style?

Comment: I do not think that this is possible. However, I think you could extend the existing styles using `BaseOn` in your new style. That way you have one style with the binding and one without but still have the style only coded once.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really reuse a binding resource as-is but you could create a markup extension that applies the resource as suggested here:

[Binding as a Resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36912216/binding-as-a-resource)