# C# WPF Same Command for Multiple events

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application in C# that follows MVVM pattern. I have a written the following code in xaml for double click event in a datagrid that will invoke a command.

```
<DataGrid.InputBindings>
    <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick"
                  Command="{Binding LoadDetailGridCommand}">
        <MouseBinding.CommandParameter>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Converter}">
                <Binding ElementName="dgInvDetails" Path="SelectedItem"/>
                <Binding ElementName="dgInvDetails" Path="CurrentColumn"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </MouseBinding.CommandParameter>
    </MouseBinding>
</DataGrid.InputBindings>
```

I want the same to be triggered when enter key is pressed. Do I have to use the same code with `KeyBinding` and set `Enter` key for the same command or is there any better way of doing this?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: There might be a better way to handle the converter and multibinding but otherwise. Yes, use a keybinding

Comment: @Andy Thank you. I have added key binding. But how else the multi binding could be optimized. I don't see a better way to do this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It depends on what you're doing and what those things are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reuse the binding, you could define it as a resource:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MultiConverter x:Key="Converter" />
    <MultiBinding x:Key="binding" Converter="{StaticResource Converter}">
        <Binding ElementName="dgInvDetails" Path="SelectedItem"/>
        <Binding ElementName="dgInvDetails" Path="CurrentColumn"/>
    </MultiBinding>
</Window.Resources>
```

...and then use [a custom markup extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36963226/7252182) to reference it:

```
<DataGrid.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Return" Command="{Binding LoadDetailGridCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{local:BindingResourceExtension binding}" />
    <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding LoadDetailGridCommand}"
                  CommandParameter="{local:BindingResourceExtension binding}" />
</DataGrid.InputBindings>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify key binding for enter key.

Try below

```
<DataGrid>
  <DataGrid.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding LoadDetailGridCommand}" Key="Enter" >
<KeyBinding.CommandParameter>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Converter}">
                <Binding ElementName="dgInvDetails" Path="SelectedItem"/>
                <Binding ElementName="dgInvDetails" Path="CurrentColumn"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </KeyBinding.CommandParameter>
</KeyBinding>
  </DataGrid.InputBindings>
</DataGrid>
```