# How can I include CommandBindings xaml code to many views in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, templates, include

I'm new to WPF so I don't know how to use same code in xaml (similar as include in C++) .
I have this snippet:

```
<Control.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="routecommand:CommandRoute.AddRecord" CanExecute="CanToolbarAddRecord" Executed="OnToolbarAddRecord" />
    <CommandBinding Command="routecommand:CommandRoute.EditRecord" CanExecute="CanToolbarEditRecord" Executed="OnToolbarEditRecord" />
    <CommandBinding Command="routecommand:CommandRoute.CopyRecord" CanExecute="CanToolbarCopyRecord" Executed="OnToolbarCopyRecord" />
    <CommandBinding Command="routecommand:CommandRoute.ExchangeData" CanExecute="CanToolbarExchangeData" Executed="OnToolbarExchangeData" />
    <CommandBinding Command="routecommand:CommandRoute.DeleteRecord" CanExecute="CanToolbarDeleteRecord" Executed="OnToolbarDeleteRecord" />
    <CommandBinding Command="routecommand:CommandRoute.LoadGridLayout" CanExecute="CanOnLoadGridLayout" Executed="OnLoadGridLayout" />
    <CommandBinding Command="routecommand:CommandRoute.SaveGridLayout" CanExecute="CanToolbarDeleteRecord" Executed="OnSaveGridLayout" />
    <CommandBinding Command="routecommand:CommandRoute.ResetGridLayout" CanExecute="CanToolbarDeleteRecord" Executed="OnResetGridLayout" />
    <CommandBinding Command="routecommand:CommandRoute.ResetAllGridLayouts" CanExecute="CanToolbarDeleteRecord" Executed="OnResetAllGridLayouts" />
  </Control.CommandBindings>
  <Control.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Esc" Command="routecommand:CommandRoute.Return" />
    <KeyBinding Key="F2" Command="routecommand:CommandRoute.EditRecord" />
    <KeyBinding Key="N" Modifiers="Ctrl" Command="routecommand:CommandRoute.AddRecord" />
    <KeyBinding Key="Space" Modifiers="Ctrl+Alt" Command="routecommand:CommandRoute.ExchangeData" />
    <KeyBinding Key="L" Modifiers="Ctrl+Shift" Command="routecommand:CommandRoute.LoadGridLayout" />
    <KeyBinding Key="K" Modifiers="Ctrl+Shift" Command="routecommand:CommandRoute.SaveGridLayout" />
    <KeyBinding Key="R" Modifiers="Ctrl+Shift" Command="routecommand:CommandRoute.ResetGridLayout" />
    <KeyBinding Key="X" Modifiers="Ctrl+Shift" Command="routecommand:CommandRoute.ResetAllGridLayouts" />
  </Control.InputBindings>
```

and I want to share the code inside lot of controls. How can I share, include, ... the code most efectively?
Thanks for help. John

Comment: You can try to put it into the resources and than create custom extension to use it, like in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36912216/binding-as-a-resource)

Comment: When you say "lots of controls" what's that mean? Are these lots of instances of one control - which could therefore be a usercontrol. Or. Different controls. In which case one way to go would be to template a contentcontrol so you could place the various controls inside something has that mark up. Or maybe this is a sort of menu in a window and you're switching out content in another part if the window. Could you also clarify what these commands will do? One candidate would be a static class but then, of course, it somehow has to be passed or work out what it is to act on.